# allowdoubleescaping=true security implications

Tags: iis, encoding

IIS does not allow doubleescaping per default, which is good practice.

1. What are the real implications if enabled?
2. How do/does a valid a attack scenario look like in this case - that
   uses double escaping?
3. And what should my application take care of if allowed?

One example might be routing from URL and reusing the string and the string might contain a + as valid character and therefore would fail the double encoding test if used within the path.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I blogged about that setting [here](https://securitytidbits.wordpress.com/2015/05/31/allowdoubleescaping-iis-request-filtering/).